# Invalid cast within EF core entity data access

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, model, entity-framework-core

I have a problem receiving an entity within my .net core service using entity framework core. 
The problem occurs when the data is selected and leads to an exception as soon as I am trying to access my `DbSet`.

I am trying to access my db set like this: 
[image: Access of the customers db set]

When I check the `_dbContext.Customers` results view I see the following error:
[image: The cast error]

So it seems like some cast of the data doesn't work. What I don't understand is why this happens. I've checked my model and my database entity and everything should be fine ...

Here's my code:

Model:

```cs
[Table("customers")]
public class Customer
{
  [Column("id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Column("code")]
  public string Code { get; set; }
  [Column("card_num")]
  public string CardNum { get; set; }
  [Column("is_valid")]
  public bool IsValid { get; set; }
  [Column("valid_from")]
  public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
  [Column("valid_to")]
  public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
  [Column("card_type")]
  public CardType CardType { get; set; }
  [Column("prepay_balance_cash")]
  public decimal PrepayBalanceCash { get; set; }
  [Column("prepay_limit_low")]
  public decimal PrepayLimitLow { get; set; }
  [Column("prepay_limit_high")]
  public decimal PrepayLimitHigh { get; set; }
  [Column("bc_contract_number")]
  public string BcContractNumber { get; set; }
}

public enum CardType
{
  Credit = 1, 
  Prepayment = 2,
  PrepaymentAndCredit = 3,
  Identification = 4,
  CreditAndPrepayment = 5
}
```

Db Context:

```cs
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  builder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
}
```

Database Table:

[image: Database table part 1]

...

[image: Database table part 2]

I really don't get it. I don't know why this is happening, I've got some other tables implemented the exact same way which work as expected. Just this one doesn't.

Anybody got an idea what's wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by setting the precision in your model as described here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types

```
public class Blog
{
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(15, 3)")]
    public decimal   PrepayBalanceCash { get; set; }
}
```

Try also with this change

```
  [Column("card_type")]
  public Decimal CardType { get; set; }
```

Comment: I use the managed mssql and the managed oracle driver selected according to the given database environment. Will this work for both database environments?

Comment: It should, though the other answer is most problably the correct one. I missed the CardType.

Comment: Removing `card_type` from the model does not affect the result so I guess I'll try your solution.

Comment: Try to keep it but return it as a decimal instead and see what's what.

Comment: With the conversion provided in david answer it seems to work for `CardType`. But now there is a cast problem regarding my `IsValid` flag. Is there an attribute way to define the way of conversion for the fields?

Comment: If the is-valid flag is true or false, change your datatype in your database to bit type.

Comment: Not able to change database types.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not way to define conversions from Property attributes.

Comment: You can check the possible attributes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Okay I fixed the conversion problems now I am encountering a null value error because some of the fields can be null. 

How can I fix those problems in a clean and consistent way? :/

Comment: You can use the ? operator. i.e. ` public DateTime? ValidFrom { get; set; }`

Comment: You might also want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types for a better design.

Answer (score 2):

Column Card_Type is defined as numeric(1,0) which will be mapped as a Decimal and your Enum will be of type Int if possible change the database column to INT.

If your using EF Core 2 then try adding a converter in the OnModelCreating,

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Customer>()
    .Property(e => e.CardType)
    .HasConversion<decimal>();
```

Not tried it so syntax may be off. But having the database store the correct type natively is more performant.

Comment: This seems to work but now I have a conversion problem for my `IsValid` field also. Are there attribute ways to define how the fields have to be converted?

Answer (score 1):

CardType property is obvious suspect. I suppose the problem in `card_type numeric(1,0)` and enum values are `Int32` type.

Comment: I also thought it would be the enum first so I already tried to load it without `card_type`, same behavior unfortunately.